# Multilevel model method in non-Bayes algo?

Tags: model, boosting, bayesian

I have learned multilevel model in Bayes methods, which I think is
really cool. Different levels data could share information which could improve the total model.  Is there any similar methods in non-Bayes algo, for example xgboost, which could share informations in different level data?

Comment: Something similar in the frequentist world is mixed-effects models, where a random-effects term tries to capture intra-group variation.

HTH.

Comment: @asifzuba  thanks for your key words,  mixed-effects models, help me a lot!